# What is the correct procedure for including a Maven-Spring-Roo-Hibernate jar in a Non-Maven-Non-Spring project?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-roo

I'm using Spring Roo to generate a bunch of Hibernate objects, inside my unit tests in the same project I can successfully read-write to the database if I do:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) 
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml"})
public class SomeTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {

@Test
public void someTest() throws Exception {
    MyUser myUser = MyUsers.findByUserId(123);
    System.out.println(myUser.getFirstName());
}
....
```

Now if I do a mvn clean install package and include the jar in an external project and do the same code:

```
MyUser myUser = MyUsers.findByUserId(123);
System.out.println(myUser.getFirstName());
```

I get "Entity manager has not been injected (is the Spring Aspects JAR configured as an AJC/AJDT aspects library?)"

I've tried creating a class inside the Spring-Roo-Hibernate project like this and adding ContextConfiguration on top of that:

```
@Service
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml"})
public class SomeClassImpl {

    public MyUser doSomething(){

        MyUser myUser = MyUsers.findByUserId(123);
                return myUser;

    }

}
```

Now when I call doSomething() in an external project:

```
public class TestDatabase {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        SomeClassImpl k = new SomeClassImpl();
        k.doSomething();
    }   
}
```

... I get the same error: 
"Entity manager has not been injected (is the Spring Aspects JAR configured as an AJC/AJDT aspects library?)"

Looking at the generated AspectJ code:

```
privileged aspect MyUser_Roo_Jpa_ActiveRecord {

    @PersistenceContext
    transient EntityManager MyUser.entityManager;

    public static final EntityManager MyUser.entityManager() {
        EntityManager em = new MyUser().entityManager;
        if (em == null) throw new IllegalStateException("Entity manager has not been injected (is the Spring Aspects JAR configured as an AJC/AJDT aspects library?)");
        return em;
    }
```

... I can see that @PersistenceContext is suppose to initialize MyUser.entityManager() which it is not when the project is jarred and included in an external project. How would one go about manually initializing the entityManager ? Or is there another way to initialize the context in the spring project when it's using it as an included library which will initialize the entityManager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the application  context don't aware about the model.  You are creating the model out of the appcontext. if you get the Model using getBean("MyUser");  some thing like that will work. else auto-wire the model and use that model for your crud operations.

You can see the following code in MyUser - @PersistenceContext rotected transient EntityManager entityManager; Then only the entityManager object will  initialized inside the the Myuser.

```
   @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) 
   @ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml"})
   public class SomeTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {

       @Autowired
       MyUser myUser; // use this object for ur crud operations 

       @Test
       public void someTest() throws Exception {                
           MyUser otherObject= myUser.findByUserId(123);
           System.out.println(otherObject.getFirstName());
       }
    }
```

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the question, ProjectA is a Maven-SpringRoo-Hibernate project, unit tests are working fine in ProjectA, ProjectB is a non-maven, non-spring, non-hibernate project. ProjectA is compiled into a JAR file and included as a dependency in ProjectB, projectB is then using these Hibernate objects, but since the context is not initialised in projectA via projectB, it's failing. What I'm trying to find out is how to include projectA.jar in projectB and still be able to use the Hibernate objects from projectA in projectB.